# Is it a good practice sharing Address Table with Two Entities?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, database-design, polymorphic-associations

I have two entities in my database that both require addresses. Both can have one address per ID.

The Venue Table:

```
create_table "venues", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "name"
 t.text     "description"
 t.string   "email"
 t.string   "phone"
 t.integer  "category_id"
 t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
end
```

The User table

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "first_name"
 t.string   "surname"
 t.string   "email"
 t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
end
```

The address table for venues has two columns are not necessary for the users. The latitude and longitude columns.

In this case, is it a good approach create an address table with a foreign key to users and other address table with a foreign key to venue? What is the best solution for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a general answer for entities where some subset of the entities have extra attributes. As such it may or may not be suitable for your particular application but it may well be worth evaluating.

Have all the addresses in one table. This is almost without exception the best practice. Create a separate table to hold the coordinates. As this is a 1-1 relationship, the PK of this table is also the FK to the addresses to which they are bound.

```
create table Coords(
    AddrID    int  not null primary key
      references Addresses( ID ),
    Latitude  CoordType not null,
    Longitude CoordType not null
);
```

What I would add would be a bit of convenience to the app developers. Front the Users and Venues table with views that exposes the table data with the address data appended.

```
create view UsersWithAddr as
  select  u.f1, u.f2, ..., a.f1, a.f2,...
  from    Users u
  join    Addresses a
      on  a.ID = u.AddrID;


create view VenuesWithAddr as
  select  v.f1, v.f2, ..., a.f1, a.f2,..., c.Latitude, c.Longitude
  from    Users u
  join    Addresses a
      on  a.ID = u.AddrID
  join    Coords c
      on  c.AddrID = a.ID;
```

So when the app is working with users, the address data is there with no spurious coordinate fields which would be set to NULL. When the app is working with venues, the address is there along with the coordinate data without the app having to worry about how that data is maintained.

Now your tables are fully normalized (assuming they are normalized without the address data), you don't have to worry about unneeded fields containing NULLs and the app will see the address data in the forms they expect to see depending if they are looking at users or venues.